# cordova compile error phonegap-plugin-push android

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugin-fcm

hi (sorry for my english) im development one app with cordova, i had compile before my app including 3 diferent plugins and it works, today i've install phonegap-plugin-push and install ok the plugin but when i going to compile generated this error:

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\domicilios\platforms\android\phonegap-plugin-push\hellocordova-push.g
  radle' line: 38
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
  Failed to apply plugin     [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlu
  gin'] > For input string: "+"

line 38 on hellocordova-push.gradle fili is this

```
ext.postBuildExtras = {
 apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
}
```

thanks.

Comment: I've got the SIMILAR issue, have u managed to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution for your issue is documented [here](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase#includegradle-failed-to-apply-plugin--for-input-string-). You probably have another plugin depending on Google Play Services (Google Maps, perhaps). so you  need to pin to a specific play services version to make it work accordingly.